# How do I set the active tab in bootstrap accordion?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I'm hunting documentation and hacking classes.  Nothing is working. All I want to do is set the active tab in a bootstrap accordion.  That's it. I want to build a page (Laravel Blade), pull a variable from the session and use that to set the active accordion tab.

There must, surely be a way to do it?

Comment: Can you post your code? Do you mean "tabs" or accordion panels?

Comment: Accordion panels.  In JQueryUI I set 'active: x' in the constructor.and we're done.  In Bootstrap it's sorcery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way. Using jquery--

```
$('.accordions').find('.panel-heading  
 a[data-toggle="collapse"]').addClass('actives');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Set the `in` class on the active `collapse` panel..

```
<div id="myCollapsePanel" class="collapse in">..</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/W4zMVTa6kP